# bootstrap4 carousel - stop slide in 'slide.bs.carousel' event

Tags: javascript, carousel, bootstrap-4

I am trying to have two steps with **bootstrap4 carousel**:

- First carousel item is for **authentication** (it username and password fields)
- Second one is for **authorization** (lists the groups that the user has access and asks him to choose one)

I want to check if the user id and password is valid *before* moving to the next slide by javascript code. I have `.carousel('pause')` but I cannot prevent moving to the next slide. Also I do not want to have an extra button to check the contents.

```
$('#myCarousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) {
    // authentication check here

    if (isAuth === false) 
    {
        // stay on this slide
    }
    else
    {
        // move the next one
    }

})
```

Is there any way for doing that?

Note: I disabled auto sliding by setting `data-interval="false"`. The user navigates between slides manually i.e. by clicking or by arrow keys.

Comment: Can you post the rest of your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To stop the slide once the `slide.bs.carousel` event has been triggered, call `preventDefault()` on the event variable. This applies to slide events triggered both automatically and manually.

```
$('#myCarousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) {
    // checks here        
    if (stop) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
})
```

See [here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/9936bf59444c402b653f28449529eab83794e911/js/src/carousel.js#L362-L365) for the relevant bits from the Bootstrap source.

If you have automatic cycling enabled, this will also allow you to pause the carousel, as it won't automatically resume later in the slide function (see [here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/9936bf59444c402b653f28449529eab83794e911/js/src/carousel.js#L421)).

See [here](https://jsfiddle.net/5nbbfnr0/) for an example (JSFiddle).

Answer (score 1):

Use this way:

```
$('#myCarousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) {
// authentication check here

if (isAuth === false) 
{
   $('#myCarousel').carousel('pause');
   return false; // stay on this slide
}
else
{
   $('#myCarousel').carousel('cycle');
   return true; // move the next one
}
```

})